# P2V for Windows 7 fails on vmware vCenter

Tags: windows-7, vmware-vcenter, vmware-fusion, physical-to-virtual

Today I started to convert my physical x64 Windows 7 laptop to using the tool vmware vCenter Standalone converter for my mac book pro.

The progress failed at the level of %98.

The error is :

```
FAILED: Unable to find the system volume, reconfiguration is not possible.
```

I think there is a trick to achieve but I couldn't make it.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

It is rather hard to diagnose without logs. And as a convenience, the Converter Standalone not only produces plenty of them by default, but also offers an [option to export them via the GUI](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010633). Also, it is always helpful to include software versions of the used products.

Working with what you've provided, the error apparently occured in the phase of reconfiguration of the virtualized system. Apparently, the Converter was unable to access the system volume. You could retry the conversion but choose a different type of storage controller (BusLogic) in order to work around a possible Converter bug. Also, make sure that the storage controller driver is present on your machine before conversion. Read [KB 1005208](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005208) for further instructions.